# My javascript won't load in python-flask

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm attempting to load a piece of javascript funconality into my index.html
however when I load in flask it doesn't seem to be working.I am not an JS expert however I'm assuming it's JS Faulty because I've made sure everythings on right directory and being loaded correctly. Please take a look at what I'm doing wrong.

base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flask-Mobility example</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
app\static\index.js
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>

    <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/index.css') }}">

    <!-- multistep form -->
    <form id="msform">
      <!-- progressbar -->
      <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
        <li>Social Profiles</li>
        <li>Personal Details</li>
      </ul>
      <!-- fieldsets -->
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
        <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
        <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
        <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

index.js

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Could you include your `base.html` template?

Comment: Added it it on the main thread.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwevzy that's the codepen I'm fllowing.

Comment: That codepen is using jQuery (and a plugin), which I don't see in your code. They are in the JS settings: `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js` and `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js`,

Comment: I added that, it didn't seem to work.

Comment: <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>


<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/index.css') }}">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `script` tags to the bottom.

If written at the top, they have nothing to reference. For instance, `$(".next")` isn't actually matching anything since the elements with that class haven't been created.

Comment: <body>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-one-page-nav/3.0.0/jquery.nav.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>

</body>

Comment: I put it on the bottom, doesn't seem to work. I also added it under base.html.

Comment: If these are the scripts you're including, it won't work. You aren't including jquery, and jquery-one-page wasn't mentioned in the codepen. Just add jquery, jquery-easing and your index, in that order.

Answer (score 0):

|FlaskApp
----|FlaskApp
--------|**templates**
----------- *html files are here*
--------|**static**
----------- *css and javascript files are here*

script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('**static**', filename='**javascript**.js') }}"